# After I re-installed SSRS 2014 (with default config) I get HTTP 404 when I try to access the ReportServer or Reports pages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssrs

I have SQL Server 2014 Express with Advanced tools installed. I had a previous installation, but I uninstalled the SQL instance and Reporting Services and then re-installed them.

Right now, I'm unable to access `http://localhost/Reports` or `http://localhost/ReportServe`r and I get a

> HTTP 404 Page not found error.

Initially, probably stupidly, I thought it was because IIS isn't installed, so I installed that, but that didn't do anything.

I also tried changing the virtual directory names then applying, but that also didn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not exactly sure what went wrong, but I reinstalled the whole SQL Server and then it worked again (as apposed to reinstalling only a few components last time.

Comment: What components did you reinstall ?